# logstash forwarder set environment variable value

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I have rails application and different environment like development , staging and production , RAILS_ENV set that value. I want to add that field in the logstash for filterization of environment, so my question where do I set that variable and how , in logstash config or logstash forwarder

Answer (score 2):

Both, logstash and logstash forwarder are possible.

### 1) Logstash Forwarder

From logstash forwarder [readme](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder):

> Any part of config can use environment variables as $VAR or ${VAR}.
>   They will be evaluated before processing JSON, allowing to pass any
>   structure.

**Example forwarder.conf:**

```
"files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "./example.log"
      ],
      "fields": { 
        "type": "example",
        "env": "$RAILS_ENV"
        }
    }
  ]
```

**Note:** Logstash forwarder > 0.4.0 required

You can build the latest version following the [instructions on github](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder#building-it).

---

### 2) Logstash

In logstash you can set fields from environment variables using the [environment filter.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-environment.html)

**Example:**

```
filter {
     environment {
          add_field_from_env => { "ENV" => "RAILS_ENV" }
     }
}
```

Comment: if I set "env": "$RAILS_ENV" in logstash-forwarded I get this result ""env":"$RAILS_ENV" means not get the variable value

Comment: I've tested that. It works as expected for me. Are you using windows or linux? Did you try `"env": "${RAILS_ENV}"` ?

Comment: My client is linux where logstash-forwarder install, here is the line ""fields": { "type": "syslog", "application_name": "Myapp", "env": "${RAILS_ENV}" }" .... I have tested with echo the variable name is working

Comment: Guess I found the problem. Do you use the latest version of logstash forwarder? The version from the elastic website (0.4.0) does not support env variables. Support was added on 15th July 2015. See: https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder/pull/435 You can get the current version from [github](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder) and build it yourself using [go](https://golang.org/).

Comment: actually client would be the AWS elasitc beanstalk and might be 100 + servers

Comment: You could build your own version just once and execute a command on those platforms to get it and install it. I'm afraid, otherwise logstash forwarder will not be able to read env variables.

Comment: I am using 0.4.0 and still result show me "env:$RAILS_ENV" not the value suggestion

Comment: Yes, 0.4.0 is too old. 0.4.0 does not support env variables. You need a newer version to get logstash forwarder to read env variables. However, elastic does not provide a newer version on their website. You need to build it yourself from github. See the link in my answer for instructions.